# Lost windows 10 product key

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-activation

I have brought windows 10 (cd/dvd)
And after long time I need to format my pc.
So I did it and now I am not getting my product key.
Means I lost the outer cover of cd..
Now I have only the cd.
Can I find my product key.
Edit: 1. I have changed the motherboard. 2. I dont know the type(ie.oem/retail etc.) There is written as "full version " on the cd.

Comment: If your hardware has not changed, it will automatically activate.

Comment: Are you trying to reinstall on same PC?  If so just click on "*I forgot*" or "*I don't have a key*" when prompted and Windows will activate using the digital license stored on MS servers.

Comment: @lx07 not entirely accurate. Same pc but with hardware changed may cause problems.

Comment: @LPChip AFAIK, the only hardware that would matter is the motherboard, as the product key is attached to the machine ID of the motherboard.

Comment: During install, click Skip when it asks for the product key (install from most recent ISO, not from the DVD).  Once you run Windows Update, it will auto-activate if you're using the same MB. Once activated, use [Belarc Advisor](https://www.belarc.com/products_belarc_advisor) to list all your product and license keys in an organized document.  For future reference, there is a tiny ~8 character code in black ink on the CoA (Certificate of Authenticity) - write it down and store it a few different places, as Microsoft will replace any CoA with a new one, provided you provide them with that code.

Comment: To all...thank you for help but i forgot to mention that i have changed the motherboard

Comment: Unless you bought a **Retail** license for Windows 10, changing motherboards constitutes changing computers and you are required to obtain a new Windows license.

Comment: @Monica That is the way Microsoft would like to have it. But in a lot of countries the judicature is different, especially if you bought the license separately and not got it with the PC.

Comment: Call Microsoft activation phone number and whine and cry, they will give you a new key.

Comment: @Robert If the license was bought separately then it's **retail**, so the previous comment about needing a new one isn't applicable, retail licenses can be reused in different machines as long as it's on one at the time. **OEM** licenses can't. It's the same in ALL jurisdictions.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia You can buy OEM Windows licenses legally stand-alone without PC, at least here in Europe. Some months ago even a common supermarket in Germany had Windows/Office OEM licenses for sale for a very cheap price.

Comment: @Robert No, you can't. That some stores and even a supermarket according to you do it doesn't mean it's legal. They may go away with it until Microsoft takes notice 

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Microsoft and Oracle and all the other tries to stop this by their layers, but they mostly failed. If a product has been sold once in Europe the "manufacturer" does not have the right to restrict you in selling it to to a third person. That is European (or German?) law. Therefore if you have an OEM license that is not physically bound to a PC you can sell it.

Comment: @Robert I live in Europe and there's no such European law. It could be a German thing only but very unlikely. Please share with us something supporting your claim. An OEM license is, by definition, attached to hardware and cannot be sold separately.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia It is European law: [used licenses can be sold individually](http://curia.europa.eu/juris/document/document.jsf?text=&docid=124564&pageIndex=0&doclang=en&mode=req&dir=&occ=first&part=1&cid=520401). Even splitting volume licenses is possible. Therefore you can buy stand-alone OEM licenses legally and use them.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for the link. Now, you should read carefully and then explain why a case of transfer of ownership of a software product licence is relevant for Microsoft's OEM licence VS retail. FYI, both are and always were transferable, the OEM along with the hardware, and the retail one can be resold. This was probably the point of contention that the courts decided in favor of the end users. The Microsoft Windows OEM licenses are valid and there are no clauses in it that violate European consumers laws. Yours is a very loose and unfounded interpretation of something unrelated.